# Why is my query returning null values when I have a NOT NULL clause in my where statement

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get DISTINCT and NOT NULL values but this doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ITEM 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE ITEM IS NOT NULL
```

This returns DISTINCT values but it also returns NULL VALUES.

sample:

```
ITEM
a
a
b
b
c
c
NULL
```

output:

```
a
b
c
NULL
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your query. I suspect your data. Try this where clause. `WHERE ITEM IS NOT NULL AND ITEM <> 'NULL'`

Comment: The answer you accepted can not explain the results you say that you were getting. Is `ITEM` a `varchar(max)` column that was previously `text`? IF so [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10295771/73226)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. "IS NOT NULL" and "IS NULL" does not work with blank values. You can cover both, if the column allows blank.

```
SELECT 
   DISTINCT item FROM table 
WHERE 
   ISNULL(item,'') <> ''
```

Comment: True, but why would this blank values result in NULL or "NULL" output?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: This where clause *will filter BLANK values* and NULL values. However, it will not filter 'NULL' values. I am confused.

Comment: @pst: I'm with you on this. If there are values with the string NULL this won't work: and they must exist if IS NOT NULL fails and we see NULL in the output- So -1 to this answer

Comment: I will take the criticism as didn't expect the string "NULL" to be physically in the data. Also everyone expects every schema too perfect on how it stores data. If the column truly does not accept null as value (not "NULL" string), then best choice is NULLIF(item,'NULL') IS NOT NULL.

Answer (score 3):

This statement will return `a b c` unless you have the *string* NULL not the `symbol` in the column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ITEM FROM TABLE WHERE ITEM IS NOT NULL
```

To test this out, try these

```
--check for
SELECT DISTINCT ITEM FROM TABLE WHERE ITEM = 'NULL'

--modify original query
SELECT DISTINCT ITEM FROM TABLE WHERE NULLIF(ITEM, 'NULL') IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Did you mean "NULLIF(ITEM, 'NULL') <> 'NULL'?

Comment: @Ben Thul: NULLIF will change the string 'NULL' to ymbol/value NULL. So this works.

Answer (score 1):

Check if Item is of type Varchar and you are storing the value "NULL" in it. If so then please try the query given below:

```
select distinct item from table where ISNULL(item,'')<>'' and item <> "NULL"
```

Comment: That clause is over-complicated and will also *suppress blank fields*! I think that `ITEM <> 'NULL' AND ITEM IS NOT NULL` may be better suited here.