# What Transact Sql nvarchar value is not null and <> '' and datalength = 0?

Tags: sql-server

What Transact-SQL `nvarchar` value is not null and <> '' and datalength = 0?

I have a table with `Field1` of data type `nvarchar(max)`. For the value of `Field1` in one particular record, the following statements are true:

- Field1 is not null
- DataLength(Field1) = 0
- Cast(IsNull(Field1, '') As nvarchar(1000)) is null

I am presuming `Field1 <> ''` because `Cast('' As nvarchar(1000))` is not null.

Background: Cast(IsNull(Field1, '') As nvarchar(1000)) is throwing an error from a stored procedure trying to insert that value where null is not allowed. When I modified the statement to use

```
 IsNull(Cast(Field1 As nvarchar(1000)), '')
```

instead, things were happy. This issue has occurred twice in a remote clients database and I do not know how to reproduce it at will.

A backup copy of their database restored on my machine no longer had this issue. Is this some kind of database corruption?  Or is there some character / collation combination that satisfies the conditions above?

Thank you for your input.

Comment: Was the data originally `ntext` and then upgraded to `nvarchar(max)`? If so might be the issue here http://stackoverflow.com/q/10295771/73226

Comment: There are probably a number of special characters that could cause this.  You might consider using the ASCII() function to analyze the contents of the field.

Comment: @MartinSmith No, it's been nvarchar(max) for a long time.

Comment: @TabAlleman do you know of an example special character that evaluates datalength = 0?

Comment: Sounds like a corrupted null bitmap then. `DATALENGTH` measures bytes and won't care what characters are in there. Not sure why you wouldn't get this on your restored backup though. Is there more than one copy of the value? Is it `INCLUDE-`d in any indexes?

Comment: @MartinSmith It is not included in any indexes.  On two occasions, I have restored a backup copy of a database with this behavior and both times I could not reproduce the behavior of the original.  I don't know enough about null bitmaps to conjecture if a backup/restore would resolve the issue but it sounds reasonable.  What maintenance would fix a corrupt null bitmap on a live database?  Thank you.

Comment: Not off the top of my head, no.   I would use ASCII() to investigate if I were the one having this problem.

Comment: You should run `DBCC CHECKDB` and see if that picks up anything. The accepted answer in the linked question also says `UPDATE Test SET Field1= Field1` worked for that particular case.

Comment: @MartinSmith you get my accepted answer.  I found out my earlier comment was wrong and there was a recent conversion from ntext.  Thanks so much.